# Batch file for copying files help needed

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I am trying to run a command that copies all files from one folder with subfolders into anther folder, but without any subfolders...

I have this:

```
for /r d:\uploadfolder %f in (*) do @copy "%f" d:\test /y
```

It works perfectly if I paste it into the command prompt.  But if I save it into a .bat file and try to run it I get the following error:

```
f" d:\test /y was unexpected at this time
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong!

I am trying this on Windows Server 2003.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Change `%f` to `%%f`. When in a batch file, you need to use two `%` characters, as specified in the help of the `for` command.